# How to replace map and filter with reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
this.serverlist = data.NodeList.map((a) => {
  if (a.productTypeId === "1") {
    return a.HostName;
  }
});

this.serverlist = this.serverlist.filter((x) => {
  return x !== undefined;
});
```

And I want to replace this 2 statements(`.map` & `.filter`) with `.reduce`. How do I do that?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Only reason you have to filter out `undefined` values from the `serverlist` is because you conditionally return a value from the callback function of `map()`. If you need to find a particular item in the array, then you can use the `find()` method.

Comment: "How do I do that?" - You are mistaken - the problem you're describing is not what `reduce` is for. `reduce` is for when you want to reduce the entire list to a single-value, which is not what you're doing. Just chain `map` and `filter` together.

Comment: @Yousaf actually I have an array of objects and I want to filter out only the `Hostname` property only when `productId` is 1. And then I want to sort the `hostname`. When I map over in the 1st statement, I received `undefined` as well since those arrays did not have `productId` value as 1. So I filtered out the undefined values

Comment: If you only need the `Hostname` property of the object with `productId` 1, then why not just filter the object with `productId` 1? Why use `map()`?

Comment: @Yousaf The OP didn't say that there would only ever be a _single_ `a` object with `productTypeId === '1'.

Comment: @Dai i understand that. What i was suggesting is what you did in your answer. I meant to remove the `map()` method call that creates an array with `undefined` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could understand your snippet as

```js
const NodeList = [
  { productTypeId: "1", HostName: "abc.com" },
  { productTypeId: "2", HostName: "abc.com" },
  { productTypeId: "1" },
  { productTypeId: "1", HostName: "xyz.com" },
]

let serverlist = NodeList.map(a => {
  if (a.productTypeId === "1") {
    return a.HostName
  }
})

serverlist = serverlist.filter(x => {
  return x !== undefined
})

console.log(serverlist)
// [ 'abc.com', 'xyz.com' ]
```

So you could combine to use reduce like this, do filter and get relevant pieces of data in one go

```js
const NodeList = [
  { productTypeId: "1", HostName: "abc.com" },
  { productTypeId: "2", HostName: "abc.com" },
  { productTypeId: "1" },
  { productTypeId: "1", HostName: "xyz.com" },
]

const serverlist = NodeList.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.productTypeId === "1" && el.HostName) {
    acc.push(el.HostName)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(serverlist)
```

Comment: Your use of `reduce` is identical to `filter+map` though - but now your function can't take advantage of optimized `filter` implementations provided by the JS runtime (e.g. it isn't parallelizable anymore).

Comment: @Dai hmm, as far as I know, the OP only mentioned rewriting into `reduce`, rather than mentioned anything about further optimization or anything else. So I do not take those other things in my answer

Comment: Yep - except I argue that the OP is wrong to want to rewrite it to use `reduce` in the first place ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution . Its working. I understand the discussion about not using reduce in this case, but I was asked to replace the statements with `reduce`. So this answer helped :)

Comment: NodeList is an existing js class. It shouldn't be used as a variable name.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 4):

> And I want to replace this 2 statements(`.map` & `.filter`) with `.reduce`. How do I do that?

You can't and you shouldn't.

The `.reduce` function is for when you want to reduce **the entire collection to a *new* single value (or object)** such as when you're aggregating values (e.g. SUM, Count, etc) or populating a `Set<T>` which is not what you're doing.

Instead just chain `map` and `filter` together (and use `filter` first to eliminate the possibility of encountering `undefined`).

Like so:

```
this.serverList = data.NodeList
    .filter( a => a.productTypeId === '1' && typeof a.HostName === 'string' )
    .map( a => a.hostName )
    .sort();
```

---

Note that while `.filter` and `.map` return *new* `Array` objects, the `.sort()` function does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution. I get it that I should proceed with map and filter.But actually I was asked to use reduce instead of  map and filter.  So, I will have to go with the other answer. Thanks once again for the help :)

Comment: @pranami **There is no advantage to using `reduce`** though - as I wrote in a comment-reply to the other answer: your script will likely run more slowly because browsers/engines cannot optimize `.reduce` the same way they can `.filter+.map`. Please tell us **why** you feel you have to use `.reduce` - it seems to me like you're on a [Fool's Errand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fool%27s_errand).

Comment: @pranami 1. Although you can get the desired output using `reduce()` - it's not the right method to use in this case. 2. Code in this answer is much more readable and clean as compared to the one using `reduce()`.

Comment: @Yousaf The OP said they were "asked to" - presumably by their boss or client. I wish more people saw their job as _working together to find the best solution_ for their boss/client instead of simply following orders, unquestioned. _le sigh_.

Comment: Dai , @Yousaf okay, got it. Let me check with the person who reviewed my code. I will discuss this. Thanks for the help :)